# How do I remove a Facebook "Insights For My Domain" Reference

Tags: facebook-insights, insight

I have Facebook "Insights For My Domain" added to my Facebook Insights account.  I have an old domain that is no longer in use and would like to remove the domain from my Facebook Insights account.  Can you please direct me to some directions regarding if and how this can be done?

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the application in developers.facebook.com/apps corresponding to the old domain.Then the Insights for that will be deleted

Comment: what can I do if I don't have any app? I added the domain only